# Sort the list in a class that is requested from the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class that contains a list of parameters. For example:

```
public class Container
{
   public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
   puplic string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Class Сontainer obtained from the database through Entity Framework. Many classes contain Container. I need to ensure that all classes that contain Сontainer and also retrieved from the database containing the sorted list of Parameters. That is, the Container must sort Parameters or request step or immediately thereafter. 
How this can be achieved?
Maybe write to the configuration

```
internal class ContainerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Container>
{
    public ContainerConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Container");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        ... ???
    }
}
```

Or wright in dataSet

```
        protected override IQueryable<Container> DataSet(DbContext db)
        {
            return db.Set<ProcessMeasurer>()                
                .Include(it => it.Parameters.Select(p => p.Parameter));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for solving the problem:

Create your attribute and specify which field to use for sorting by default:

```
public class DefaultOrderFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DefaultOrderFieldAttribute()
    {
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}

[DefaultOrderField(FieldName = "ParameterName")]
public partial class Parameter
{
}
```

Write a Visitor, which in the case of detection of our attribute modifies select:

```
public class DefaultOrderVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
{
    public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
    {
        const string NAMESPACE = "OrderTest";

        var type =
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}", NAMESPACE, expression.Target.Name));

        var attribute =
            type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DefaultOrderFieldAttribute)).SingleOrDefault() as
                DefaultOrderFieldAttribute;

        if (attribute != null)
            return expression.OrderBy(ex => ex.Property(attribute.FieldName));

        return expression;
    }
}
```

Put in our Visitor Interceptor:

```
 public class DefaultOrderInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
            {
                var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;

                if (queryCommand != null)
                {
                    var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new DefaultOrderVisitor());
                    interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        queryCommand.DataSpace, newQuery);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and register it in the configuration (this class just has to be in the same assembly as the model):

```
public class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
        {
            AddInterceptor(new DefaultOrderInterceptor());
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the answer below is also a good. 
When he put -1 I did not finish it

Answer (score -1):

Need to work with the entity class.
If we want to sort the collection was in all the elements that comprise it, we have to change the appropriate property.
Obvious variant - creating property setter.

```
private List<Parameter> _parameters;
public List<Parameter> Parameters
{
   get { return _parameters; }
   set { _parameters = value.OrderBy(...).ToList();
}
```

But the behavior of the compiler (call the setter once, and the multiple callin to the getter) gave me a reason to assume that the target collection is not put in a property all at once. The items in the query is gradually added to the collection. Therefore, sorting in setter does not always work.
Therefore, we must carry out sorting the return value

```
get
{
   if(_parameters == null) return null;                
   _parameters = _parameters.OrderBy(...).ToList();
   return _parameters;
}
```

It works. But the problem is that an appeal to the getter, and hence sorting, will be carried out when EntityFramework inserts each value. This affects the performance.

The best variant that I know at the moment is to inherit all entities from the interface with the function Prepare

```
public interface IEntity
{
   void Prepare();
}
```

and implement it in each class model. Models that comprise other models cause a method to prepare, for each desired properties.

```
public class SomeModel : IEntity
{
   public CustomType SomeProperty { get; set; }
   public OneMoreCustomType AnotherProrerty { get; set; }

   public void Prepare()
   {
      SomeProperty.Prepare();
      AnotherProperty.Prepare();
   }
}
```

For the respective classes it will take appropriate action. Including sorting.
Сall a method to prepare the Сontainer (in this case) you before using. 
For example, in the Business Logic (MVPVM).

Comment: And that is what? It is not an answer. -1.

Comment: Describe my thoughts, experiments and suggestions on this issue.

Comment: But if anyone knows the solution to this problem using standard EntityFramework tools, or just the best option, please share.